# Can Mac Outlook 2011 use in-reply-to to group messages?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook-2011

Outlook 2011 on the Mac uses `Subject:` to group messages into conversations, which often leads to confusion when your mailbox contains unrelated messages with the same subject line. The correct way to do things is to use the "In-reply-to:" header, and the older Outlook on my Windows XP box seems to do this just fine. Is there any way to make Mac Outlook 2010 behave the same way?

Answer (score 0):

A conversation is always organized by subject, because several persons may take part in
one conversation. So that is not the mechanism you want.

Apart from conversations, one can also
[Group or ungroup email messages in your Inbox](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/group-or-ungroup-email-messages-in-your-inbox-HA010355075.aspx),
which gives you the possibility of choosing the fields you want to group by.

Comment: Since most decent mail clients use "in-reply-to" to group messages into tree-like threads, it is absolutely what I want. The group-by feature doesn't include in-reply-to as an option, although if it did, it still wouldn't do the right thing.

Comment: In the Microsoft world one doesn't always have a choice. If you can't find that Outlook fits your needs, there are alternate (decent) mail clients.